# How do you override the ContextMenu that appears when right clicking on winforms WebBrowser Control?

Tags: .net, winforms, browser, contextmenu

When you right click on WebBrowser control, the standard IE context menu with options such as "Back", "View Source", etc. appears.

How do I make my own ContextMenuStrip appear instead? WebBrowser.ContextMenuStrip doesn't work for this Control.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of the other solutions on this site made it sound like this was very difficult to do because it was a COM object... and recommended adding a new class "ExtendedWebBrowser".  For this task, it turns out to be pretty simple.

In your code which adds a web browser control, add the DocumentCompleted event handler.

```
    WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
```

Define these event handlers (change contextMenuStrip to match name of the one you created).

```
    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser) sender;
        browser.Document.ContextMenuShowing += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Document_ContextMenuShowing);
    }

    void Document_ContextMenuShowing(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        // If shift is held when right clicking we show the default IE control.
        e.ReturnValue = e.ShiftKeyPressed; // Only shows ContextMenu if shift key is pressed. 

        // If shift wasn't held, we show our own ContextMenuStrip
        if (!e.ReturnValue)
        {
            // All the MousePosition events seemed returned the offset from the form.  But, was then showed relative to Screen.
            contextMenuStripHtmlRightClick.Show(this, this.Location.X + e.MousePosition.X, this.Location.Y + e.MousePosition.Y); // make it offset of form
        }
    }
```

Note: my override does the following:
  * if shift is held down when you right click it shows IE return value.
  * Otherwise it shows the contextMenuStripHtmlRightClick (definition not shown in this example)